# SwiftUI SignInWithAppleButton dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using a [SignInWithAppleButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/signinwithapplebutton) in my SwiftUI Application. However when I put my device into dark mode the button does not automatically change into the color scheme for dark backgrounds proposed by the human interface guidelines. Can I enable that behavior without manually defining the colors.

```swift
struct AuthenticationView: View {
    
    var authManager = AuthManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        SignInWithAppleButton(
            onRequest: { request in
                authManager.createRequest(request)
            },
            onCompletion: { result in
                authManager.handleResult(result)
            })
            .frame(width: 280, height: 45, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason the button doesn't update automatically with the color scheme, but you can fix it with the code below:

```
struct AuthenticationView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    let authManager = AuthManager()

    private var buttonStyle: SignInWithAppleButton.Style {
        switch colorScheme {
        case .light: return .black
        case .dark: return .white
        @unknown default: return .black
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        SignInWithAppleButton(
            .signIn,
            onRequest: authManager.createRequest,
            onCompletion: authManager.handleResult
        )
        .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(buttonStyle)
        .id(colorScheme)
        .frame(height: 56)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working on Sonoma / Xcode 15. The initial button style is correct when the app starts, but the button does not change style when forcing a change from light mode to dark mode while the app is running